# iOS 6: Error while updating sqlite table with text data

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I am trying to update a table in sqlite database. I get no troubles when updating ints but now I have insert (update) a text.

```
-(void)updateItemMemo:(NSString*)text itemID:(int)itemID
{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:user_data];
sqlite3* database = NULL;
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *sqlItems=sqlite3_mprintf("UPDATE itemStatus\
                                         SET memo=?\
                                         where refID=?",text,itemID);
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlItems, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)

        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 2, itemID);

    char* errmsg;
    sqlite3_exec(database, "sqlItems", NULL, NULL, &errmsg);
    sqlite3_free((char*)errmsg);

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(statement))
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_free((char*)sqlItems);
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"%s: prepare failed: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

}
```

The query is right: checked in SQLiteStudio exchanging params with text and real id. It works. The problem is that the method won't work for some mysterious reason. Also it doesn't return any errors. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, solved it. The reason was the word "text" as parameter. Just changed it to "memoContext" and it worked like charm.